# Linux md5 checksum issue

Tags: redhat, md5

I have a directory in which thousands of directories are present. I need to get md5sum of only around 60 directories from this list of thousands of directories.
How do I selectively run the md5 on a selective set of directories.

I know the below command,
find "dir_name" -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 md5sum | md5sum

But I have a list of 60 directories as the target from the list of 1000's present in the file system.

If anyone advise, it would be of great help.

Regards,
Kushal Chaudhary

Answer (score 0):

You can run through the loop.

```
for folder in `cat <file which has folder list>; do find folder -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 md5sum | md5sum;done
```